# Applescript difference from 10.6 to 10.7

Tags: applescript, spell-checking

first, I am a beginner with apple and mac os.

I have wrote a script for 10.6 to use the spellchecker within my Java-Program:

```
 tell application "Automator Runner"
    set mySpellChecker to call method "sharedSpellChecker" of class "NSSpellChecker"
    set foundLanguages to call method "availableLanguages" of mySpellChecker
 end tell
```

which works nice under 10.6

But now under 10.7.2 even under the applescript console an error occurs at:

```
tell application "Automator Runner"
   set mySpellChecker to call **method** "sharedSpellChecker" of class "NSSpellChecker"
   set foundWords to call method "availableLanguages" of mySpellChecker
end tell
```

> ** Expected end of line but found identifier.

Can anyone please give me a hint, what has changed from 10.6 to 10.7. In the Changelog I cant find either an AppleScript change or a change with the spellchecker API. Also other scripts from the web using the "to call method ..." fails with the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it seems that "call method" commands do not work any more in 10.7. Apple has been phasing this out with 10.6 and finally did away with it fully in 10.7. They have replaced this way of accessing objective-c methods with AppleScriptObjC language. As such they made an addition to applescript in 10.7. You can now write AppleScriptObjC code directly in AppleScript Editor. Under 10.6 you could only use it through Xcode. So we lost something but we gained something too. We can debate which way was better but Apple feels AppleScriptObjC is the way forward.